# Error on decompiling apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I'm trying to decompile an apk. but I face with this error:

```
Could not find the main class: brut.apktool.Main. Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" -----------------------------------------------------
---------------------
|Wed 02/26/2014 --  0:25:58.98|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: brut/apktool/Main : Unsupported major.mi
nor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: brut.apktool.Main. Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Press any key to continue . . .
```

Does any body know what is the `brut.apktool.Main` and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I installed jdk 1.7 and changed my JAV_HOME and PATH values and I get this error now:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the same using jdk 1.7 as from your log it seems you are using jdk 1.6 and the class you are decompiling has java 7 format

Comment: And what happens when you do press a key?

Comment: It closes the log page.

Comment: Might be it creates a file with the decompiled source